# Scala: combine elements in same position of two lists

Tags: scala

I've two lists and I want to obtain another list combining, in a tuple, elements in same position.

An example:

```
val x = List(1,2,3)
val y = List(4,5,6)

result = List((1,4),(2,5),(3,6))
```

Comment: You're in for some serious zipping lad!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`zip`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@zip[B](that:scala.collection.GenIterable[B]):List[(A,B)]):

```
val result = x zip y
```